# Can SymPy simplify real expressions containing exponentials with complex base?

Tags: python, sympy

The following program constructs a vector S.

```py
from sympy import *

n = symbols("n", integer=True)

M = Matrix(sympify([["1", "-1/3"], ["1/3", "8/9"]]))
A0 = Matrix(sympify(["1", "1"]))
S = M ** n
S = S * A0
print(simplify(S[0]))
print(simplify(S[1]))
```

I have

```
S[0] = 104976 ** (-n) * (-14 * (99144 - 5832 * sqrt(35) * I) ** n - 4 * sqrt(35) * I * (99144 - 5832 * sqrt(35) * I) ** n + 21 * (99144 + 5832 * sqrt(35) * I) ** n - 3 * sqrt(35) * I * (99144 + 5832 * sqrt(35) * I) ** n) / (7 * (1 - sqrt(35) * I))

S[1] = 5832 ** (-n) * (7 * (5508 - 324 * sqrt(35) * I) ** n + sqrt(35) * I * (5508 - 324 * sqrt(35)*I) ** n + 7 * (5508 + 324 * sqrt(35) * I) ** n - sqrt(35) * I * (5508 + 324 * sqrt(35) * I) ** n) / 14
```

The two components of the vector are expressions with the free symbol `n`. Both expressions are real for all integers `n` by construction. However, the expressions contain the imaginary unit, for example in the subexpression `(99144 - 5832*sqrt(35)*I)**n`. Is there a way to simplify `S` such that it does not contain the imaginary unit? I already tried using `as_real_imag()` which didn't work.

Comment: What would you expect the real/imag parts of `(99144 - 5832*sqrt(35)*I)**n` to simplify to?

Comment: I am not sure about that particular subexpression but the whole `S[0]` and `S[1]` are equivalent to real functions in `n`. I guess the imaginary unit creeps in because M has complex eigenvalues and they are used in the exponentiation algorithm. What I am trying to do here is to solve the system of linear homogeneous recurrences A_n = M*A_{n-1}.

Comment: The fact that the functions are real does not imply that there is a straight-forward way to express them without using `I`.